# Passar valor fixo para repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho meu repository, com metodo de adicionar

```
public virtual T Adiciona(T entity)
{
  _dbSet.Add(entity);
  return entity;
}
```

Não se se é possível,

Todas as minhas classes herdam de "ModelBase"

```
  public class ModelBase
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
  }
```

Essa empresaId é uma propriedade do usuário, que é a empresa que ele está vinculado

Quero gravar todos os meus models que herdam de modelbase, quero passar o id da empresa já

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Na verdade apenas altere para o seguinte:

```
public virtual T Adiciona(T entity)
{
    var empresaId = LoggedUserHelper.GetEmpresaUsuario(User);
    var objetoEmpresa = new Empresa { EmpresaId = empresaId };
    contexto.Empresas.Attach(objetoEmpresa);
    entity.Empresa = objetoEmpresa;
    contexto.Set<T>.Add(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

Esse `LoggedUserHelper` é uma classe estática mais ou menos assim:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Helpers {
    public static class LoggedUserHelper {
        private static SeuProjetoContext contexto = new SeuProjetoContext();

        public static int GetEmpresaUsuario {
            return contexto.Usuarios.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Nome == User.Identity.Name).UsuarioId;
        }
    }
}
```

Estou supondo que você usa ou `FormsAuthentication`, ou ASP.NET Membership, ou ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Cigano, por eu estar recebendo um genérico, ele nem aceita que eu passe "entity.Propriedade = valor"

Comment: @Rod Declare seu genérico como `where T: ModelBase`